# How to insert prop into a string

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I cannot figure out how to put `prop` inside a string, so I can use it in a different `jsx` file.

Code:

```
const TypingGame = (props) => {
  const initialSentence = "banana"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist thing to know that react use one-way-data flow so if you looking to send data from a parent component to a child using Props you can read it in this way

```
const ParentComponent = ()=>{
 const sentence = "banana"
return(
    <TypingGame sentence={senetence} />
);
}

const TypingGame = (props) => {
  const initialSentence = props.sentence
```

Comment: @lilfilda if this answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as accepted to show appreciation to the answerer, and upvote it in the future when you have enough reputation points, and you gain the voting privilege.